# Archimedean Copula Probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, copula

I have the following excercise :

Let C be an Archimedean copula with generator given by $\psi(x) = E[e^{
−xV} ]$, where V is
an exponentially distributed random variable with expectation 1. Calculate the probability
$P[U_1 > \frac{1}{2}, U_2 > \frac{1}{2}]$ for $(U_1, U_2) \sim C$.

I struggle to start with the solution as I seem to not be able to find a connection between the generator function and the probability. I thought I could maybe get the densities from the copula, but that is also not the case, at least I don't see it. Does someone know how to proceed?

Best

Comment: $P(U_1 > a, U_2 > b) = 1- \bigl(P(U_1 \leqslant a) + P(U_2 \leqslant b) - P(U_1 \leqslant a, U_2 \leqslant b)\bigr) = 1 - \bigl(1-a + 1 - b - C(a,b)\bigr)$. Is it what you need ?

Comment: Thank you so much for this input. I have managed to solve it, but would like to add some comments to clarify : The individual probabilities are due to the Copula having Uniform marginals. The expectation of V is given so that $\lambda$ can be determined and the copula ends up to be 0.25. The answer to the probability should then be 0.25.